# Using regex_replace in Ansible to extract a specific string

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to use regex_replace to extract just the interface names from a list of strings that includes other information about the interface.

I tried with this playbook:

```
---
- name: Ansible regex mapping
  hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    interfaces:
      - "1/1/18     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/20     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/21     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/32     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"

  tasks:
    - name: Extract interface in list
      set_fact:
        trunk_interfaces: "{{ interfaces | map('regex_replace', '^(\\S+)', '\\1') | list }}"
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ trunk_interfaces }}"
```

I was expecting:

```
  msg:
  - 1/1/18
  - 1/1/20
  - 1/1/21
  - 1/1/32
```

But I'm getting:

```
  msg:
  - 1/1/18     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 1/1/20     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 1/1/21     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 1/1/32     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
```

Comment: The entirety of your regex only contains one group and you're replacing it with its capture - which generally does nothing. You could try to change your regex to `^(\\S+).*`, which `.*` consumes everything after group 1. Then replacing it with group 1 shall get rid of everything after it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need *regex_replace*. Instead, *split* the items (by default on spaces), and get the *first* fields

```yaml
  trunk_interfaces: "{{ interfaces|map('split')|map('first')|list }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  trunk_interfaces:
    - 1/1/18
    - 1/1/20
    - 1/1/21
    - 1/1/32
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    interfaces:
      - "1/1/18     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/20     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/21     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/32     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"

    trunk_interfaces: "{{ interfaces|map('split')|map('first')|list }}"
      
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: trunk_interfaces
```

- You can split the items further

```yaml
  arr: "{{ interfaces|map('split')|list }}"
  f1: "{{ arr|map(attribute='1')|list }}"
  f2: "{{ arr|map(attribute='2')|list }}"
  f2_arr: "{{ f2|map('split', ',')|map('map', 'int')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  arr:
    - [1/1/18, '19', '8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254']
    - [1/1/20, '19', '8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254']
    - [1/1/21, '19', '8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254']
    - [1/1/32, '19', '8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254']

  f1:
  - '19'
  - '19'
  - '19'
  - '19'

  f2:
  - 8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254
  - 8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254

  f2_arr:
    - [8, 19, 108, 142, 160, 204, 208, 220, 228, 240, 254]
    - [8, 19, 108, 142, 160, 204, 208, 220, 228, 240, 254]
    - [8, 19, 108, 142, 160, 204, 208, 220, 228, 240, 254]
    - [8, 19, 108, 142, 160, 204, 208, 220, 228, 240, 254]
```

---

See: [Parsing semi-structured text with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-semi-structured-text-with-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- name: Ansible regex mapping
  hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    interfaces:
      - "1/1/18     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/20     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/21     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"
      - "1/1/32     19          8,19,108,142,160,204,208,220,228,240,254"

  tasks:
    - name: Extract interface in list
      set_fact:
        trunk_interfaces: "{{ interfaces | map('regex_replace', '^(\\S+).+$', '\\1') | list }}"
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ trunk_interfaces }}"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.